# generate customer id using string and incremental int

Tags: c#

i have this variable
string Lce = "LCE";
string number = "2005";

I want to create a customer id which have this format

"LCE10001-2005"
"LCE10002-2005"

How to increment the integer and add with those strings? I'm thinking about concatenating the string.

Comment: could you show us what you did so far with some code snippet ?

Comment: Please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and update your question or ask a new one

Comment: you can do it in multiple ways.  1. if the LCE token is the same or same length just do a substring and then parse out the int and increment it,
BUT I think it would just be easier to store the customer number in 3 seperate parts and Division,SerialNumber,Model

Comment: Do you have a long turn-around time on being able to test code changes? You say you are "thinking about concatenating the string" - but could you quickly check and see how that would work? That would make a better question, if you tried that and have a more specific problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with **johnny 5**. Basically, build the number each time you need it. The approach is going to vary highly based on how you're storing and retrieving data, i.e. locally, database, etc.

Here are some examples I whipped up.

```
// a basic string concantenation
private static string createIDex1(int idNum = 0)
{
    return "LCE" + idNum + "-2005";
}

// something more flexible with optional parameters and default arguments
// utilizing a single StringBUilder object is more memory efficient
private static string createIDex2(StringBuilder builder = null, int idNum = 0)
{
    // initialize fields and objects
    if (builder == null)
    {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    else
    {
        builder.Clear();
    }

    string prefix = "LCE";
    string suffix = "-2005";

    // combine
    builder.Append(prefix);
    builder.Append(idNum);
    builder.Append(suffix);

    return builder.ToString();
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    string custID = "";

    // some sample, auto-incrementing numbers
    // using example method 1
    for (int n = 10000; n < 10006; n++)
    {
        custID = createIDex1(n);
        Console.WriteLine(custID);
    }

    // output spacer
    Console.WriteLine();

    // using example method 2 without pasing a StringBuilder object
    for (int n = 10000; n < 10006; n++)
    {
        custID = createIDex2(null, n);
        Console.WriteLine(custID);
    }

    // output spacer
    Console.WriteLine();

    // using example method 2 while pasing a StringBuilder object
    for (int n = 10000; n < 10006; n++)
    {
        custID = createIDex2(strb, n);
        Console.WriteLine(custID);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter key to exit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
LCE10000-2005
LCE10001-2005
LCE10002-2005
LCE10003-2005
LCE10004-2005
LCE10005-2005

LCE10000-2005
LCE10001-2005
LCE10002-2005
LCE10003-2005
LCE10004-2005
LCE10005-2005

LCE10000-2005
LCE10001-2005
LCE10002-2005
LCE10003-2005
LCE10004-2005
LCE10005-2005
Press Enter key to exit
```